# CAKEPHP 3: Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() must implement interface Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, boolean given

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-3.0

**Thank you for your support**

I'm working on a project for a survey system with every questionnaire having multiple questions and in other to make adding questions i'm using Jquery to load multiple field set for all the question to be added and save at the same time Instead of adding it one after the other

but i'm having Issues with my code as it shows this error

**Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() must implement interface Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, boolean given, called in C:\wamp64\www\surveynaija\src\Controller\QuestionnairesController.php on line 65**

The line 65 refers to `$result = $questions->patchEntity($result, $this->request->getData());`

**here is the controller code**

```
public function addquestions(){
    $data[] = [
            'question' => 'question',
            'questionnaire_id' => 'questionnaire_id',
            'questiontype_id' => 'questiontype_id'
    ] ;
    $questions = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Questions');
    $entities = $questions->newEntities($data);
    $result = $questions->saveMany($entities, array('deep'=>true, 'validate'=>false, 'atomic' => true)); 
    //$question = $this->Questions->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $result = $questions->patchEntity($result, $this->request->getData());
        if ($result) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The question has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The question could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $questionnaires = $questions->Questionnaires->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $questiontypes = $questions->Questiontypes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $answers = $questions->Answers->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('result', 'questionnaires', 'questiontypes', 'answers'));
    
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
    //echo  $data['question'];
 }
```

**here is my view code**

```
<div class="questions form large-9 medium-8 columns content " >
<?= $this->Form->create($result) ?>


<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <fieldset class="input_fields_wrap" id="addForm">
    <legend><?= __('Add Question') ?></legend>
        
    
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('question');
        echo $this->Form->control('questionnaire_id', ['options' => $questionnaires]);
        echo $this->Form->control('questiontype_id', ['options' => $questiontypes]);
        echo $this->Form->control('answers._ids', ['options' => $answers]);
     
    ?>
    
</fieldset>

<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>

<?php 
    
    echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";
    
?>
```

**and here is my jquery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        var addFormField = '<?php echo $this->Form->control("question"); ?>'
            + '<?php echo $this->Form->control("questionnaire_id", ["options" => $questionnaires]); ?>'
            +    '<?php echo $this->Form->control("questiontype_id", ["options" => $questiontypes]); ?>'
             +   '<?php echo $this->Form->control("answers._ids", ["options" => $answers]);?>'
            ;
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append(addFormField); //add input box
            }
        });
        
        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clearly telling you that `$result` is a boolean when you pass it to `patchEntity`. Indeed, it's the return value from `saveMany`. Your code is very strange. It first creates a bunch of entities, saves them, *then* checks if it's a post request and if so tries to create and save a single entity?

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt i quite understand the output but then i'm trying to understand the **must implement interface Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface**  

or better still what should i do to remove the error message

Comment: It's telling you that it needs an entity passed in there. You've giving it a boolean. To remove the error message, give it an entity. Or, get rid of that code entirely, as it seems that you've modified stock code without really understanding what it's supposed to do. Sorry, but I lack the energy tonight to carefully deconstruct and correct your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question above the problem is to create a form that use the saveMany() function in cakephp

but in doing so the you need to prepare the data from the form to be in array

```
 $data = [
        [
            'title' => 'First post',
            'published' => 1
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Second post',
            'published' => 1
        ],
    ];
```

but to achieve this you need to use

```
$this->request->getData('ModelName' ['field1', 'field2', 'field3' ])
```

then following the cookbook

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records

in the view file you can use a for loop or jquery but your html output

```
<input type="text" name="Modelname[1][field]" id="modelname-1-field">
<input type="text" name="Modelname[2][field]" id="modelname-2-field">
<input type="text" name="Modelname[3][field]" id="modelname-3-field">
```

hope this serves someone someday